# Python OverflowError with truncate() on a file

Tags: python

When I used Python to create a file, `OverflowError` returned.

```
...
  File "wcpdl.py", line 69, in run
    fp.truncate(self.size)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I'm using Python 3.8.0 and the program was running on 32bit operating system. The value of `self.size` is 4669100032.

I did't know how it happened. Maybe I don't have enough disk space for file, or the number is too big?

Comment: in general `OverFlowError` means that the number is too large. And it make sense because 2,147,483,647 (the max number in 32bit system )is much smaller.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer!